# is c3p0 obsolete?

Tags: c3p0

According to http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/bin/ it seems that the last stable version of c3p0 was released in 2007.

Isn't it abandoned project?

We use it heavily and it works fine, but I am a little bit afraid that it will not get fixes and support, causing that new versions of hibernate, JDBC drivers, databases and finally transition to java7 will make it work worse.

Comment: Have you tried asking the project's administrators? http://sourceforge.net/project/memberlist.php?group_id=25357

Comment: atornblad, thank you for this comment. I asked them, as you advised.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i've been in grad school in an unrelated field since 2007, which has kicked my butt and rendered c3p0 maintenance slow at best. c3p0 is not formally abandoned, but until i'm out of this program, it defacto has been. (the update from ~1.5 yrs ago is a pretty big deal, and i've gotten no bad feedback on the changes, i advise using that. but it was a one-off, not the long sequence of release and feedback that i upgrade to a stable release.)

i do intend to bring c3p0 forward when i am done, which will hopefully be this summer. but i mostly feel terrible about the long lapse in maintenance, and understand apologetically that many users have felt compelled to seek alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

c3p0 development has started up again, with a new release (c3p0-0.9.2-pre2).

Answer (score 3):

We switched to BoneCP because we had some IOExceptions on high load we could not fix. After switching to BoneCP everything run fine. we are driving a very high volum site with peaks of 3000 dynamic page views per second and I can really recommend BoneCP.

Comment: BoneCP is now obsolete. Use c3p0 or something else

Comment: Why do you think BoneCP is obsolete? I don't think so. BoneCP works like a charm and is faster than c3p0 (see Benchmarks at bonecp project site)

Comment: I used BoneCP for a while and reverted back to c3p0 due to some bugs. Lately their website was down so I thought this project was abandoned otherwise I would have reported the bug. Sorry to have posted this without checking if their website was up

Comment: Ok, I am happy with boneCP. I just wanted to be fair to bonecp as I like it pretty much.

Comment: HikariCP is now the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 I would recommend [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). It is very fast, stable and has excellent documentation.